# Do PageSpeed Insights CWV timings filter to landing/entry visits only for a URL or include all visits to the URL?

Tags: pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals

Does anyone know if PageSpeed Insights calculates Core Web Vitals timings only incorporating data points where the URL specified is the landing/entry action for a session (visit), or if it will calculate timings whether that URL is the landing action or any other action in the session?

I'm asking this because 75th percentile timings would be different (likely higher) if we were only looking at landing actions vs if we included instances of users coming to the page cached later in a session. I would think for SEO we'd be focused more on landing action timings, but I'm not sure what methodology Google uses.

I've tried reading through the [PageSpeed Insights documentation](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about) and [CrUX documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-user-experience-report), but it's still unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

All data sourced from the [Chrome User Experience Report (CrUX)](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-user-experience-report) (which is where the field data from PageSpeed Insights comes from) is based on all page visits from users who have not opted out in some form:

From the CrUX documentation:

> The Chrome User Experience Report is powered by real user measurement...across the public web, aggregated from users who have opted-in to syncing their browsing history, have not set up a Sync passphrase, and have usage statistic reporting enabled.

So to answer your specific question, no it is not just based on landing page visits or clicks from Google Search. And yes, properly optimized caching headers and other things that improve the experience of returning visitors can help to improve your Core Web Vitals scores.